# Unable to Send mail from Gmail Account in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, gmail

I am sending mail using this code

```
  using System.Net.Mail;
  using System.Net.Security;

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress("abc@gmail.com");
    mail.To.Add("xyz@gmail.com");
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.Subject = "Email Sent";
    mail.Body = "Mail Done";
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "123456");
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Send(mail);
    Label1.Text = "Mail Sent";
```

Whem I am using **abc@gmail.com**(one email id) for sending email, mail will successfully send but when I am using **pqr@gmail.com**(another mail id) **mail sending failed**. On local server both "**abc**" & "**pqr**" working fine.

Please help me to sort out this problem.

**Error Message**

```
the smtp server requires a secure connection or the client is not authenticated the server response was 5.5.1 authentication requires
```

Comment: Which error or exception thrown while sending email from pqr@gmail.com?

Comment: are you replacing user and credentials too to pqr@gmail.com? Or only the sender?

Comment: The Credentials are fine

Comment: Do you got answer i have also faced the same.

Answer (score 1):

Update you code to the following:

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "123456");
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Send(mail);
```

Comment: Actually the code is working fine on local server. But after uploading it give the error

Comment: is the port blocked by your host?

Answer (score 0):

Try this line after the `enableSSl=true` code

```
smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
```

Comment: While this may help the OP it is almost always a better answer to include an explanation of your solution. Just giving an answer to someone does no good to helping them understand the problem or aid them in overcoming obstacles in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail has added a new security feature for not to allow sending email using the less secure apps. You have to change the settings for your gmail account to allow access by less secure apps using steps given by google at below link

https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en

**Enable less secure apps to access accounts**
1.Sign in to your Google Admin console.

2. Click Security > Basic settings.
3. Under Less secure apps, select Go to settings for less secure apps.
   In the subwindow, select the Allow users to manage their access to less secure apps radio button.
   Once you've set Allow users to manage their access to less secure apps to on, affected users within the selected group or Organizational Unit will be able to toggle access for less secure apps on or off themselves.